# New Cardboard SDK for Unity bug with S6 phones

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, google-cardboard

We are facing a problem since we updated our cardboard SDK for Unity 5.1.3f1.

In the editor we see no problems at all but once builded for android on a S6 phone (edge or not) we get some fast white flash when we switch scenes. It doesn't happen with phones such as Nexus 5.

We tried to builds empty scenes as well as the cardboard demo but we have the exact same problem which would suggest the problem is not on our project.

Anyone has/had this problem? If so is there a solution or a suggestion because we are stuck on this one.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, there are some odd behaviors seen on S6 only.  For example: https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-unity/issues/128 which could be related.  You might want to try the workaround listed there to see if it helps you too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it was indeed causing the problem.

For anyone ending up here : you need to delete stereoScreen.Create() in both the scripts Cardboard.cs and CardboardPreRender.cs and set the "distorsion correction" setting on the CardBoardHead prefab to Unity.